# Using postman desktop application, can we define a datasource?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

Im using postman desktop application. Can we define a datasource there?
I know the we can define datasource in online workspace. But i dont want to use online version.
ANyone know how to add datasource for the desktop application?

Comment: data source for which feature ?

Comment: @PDHide For POSTman REST collections(tests cases). CSV/JSON datasources I would like to add.

Comment: You mean in collection runner ?  could you add a screen shot of what you are trying to do

Comment: like what you can do in online and what you cannot do in desktop version